# Openshift, python, mongodb, and cron guidance needed

Tags: python, mongodb, openshift

I have a python web app that essentially allows 2 computers to talk with one another.  If a session ends abruptly the record is still stored in pymongo, I want to be able to run a cron job to clean up old records, but I am not clear on how to do that, can't figure how to use bash to talk to pymongo...

What else could I do, call python from the cron job?

Comment: Bash has no driver to any database as far as I know. You have to call a python script from cron that does what you need to do!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a python script using pymongo (or any other mongodb client library) that does the necessary cleanup and configure cron to run it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article on OpenShift on how to get Cron up and running 
https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/blogs/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift